# Non-Material Theme causes freeze on Text Input

Tags: android, material-design, android-theme

I am having a strange issue. When I am using the Material theme I have no issues with my app, but when I use Theme.Holo.Light I have this problem. When I click on any text field input, EditText or SearchView (the keyboard pops up) the app becomes unresponsive and freezes up, though the keyboard still types. I don't know much about themes, so I am unsure of what is causing this. I want to use Android Version 19 because I need my app to be accessible to more of the Android users, so I can't use the Material Theme with Android Version 19

Styles.xml

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="android:showAsAction">always</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">#3399ff</item>
    <item name="android:logo">@android:color/transparent</item>


</style>
<style name="MyActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/sweat_header</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/sweat_header</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/sweat_header</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Make two themes based on the lower and higher versions. I believe that would sort it out.

values/themes.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"/>

    <style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
        <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    </style>
</resources>

values-v21/themes.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
    <item name="android:windowContentTransitions">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowEnterTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowAllowReturnTransitionOverlap">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementEnterTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
    <item name="android:windowSharedElementExitTransition">@android:transition/move</item>
</style>
</resources>

Hope it helps.
```

Comment: I can't have a v21 xml because I am building with and targeting api level 19, not 21

Comment: I believe it has to do more with the code in the main layout than theme. It would be better if you posted the Main Activity code. If not, I would suggest you to make a new project and start from base.